# libfuzzer Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: linux, segmentation-fault, clang++, libfuzzer

Have followed the instructions to create a fuzzer using libfuzzer with ASAN support.  I point it at a corpus and it will generally run for a few days and then I'll get a message:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
INFO: exiting: 139 time: XXXXXXs
```

I cannot locate a core dump file anywhere on my system.

Some troubleshooting that I've applied:

1. I have coded real memory errors into my application and when run as a fuzzer, it DOES produce a crash file.
2. I have run other binaries with deliberate memory errors and they DO produce core dump files in the working directory.

My environment is Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-66-generic x86_64).
The compiler is clang++-11.

I have posted a snip of the output immediately prior to the Segmentation fault below:

```
#1253299: cov: 54386 ft: 261993 corp: 3483 exec/s 0 oom/timeout/crash: 0/0/0 time: 540397s job: 6782 dft_time: 0
INFO: log from the inner process:
INFO: Seed: 614118371
INFO: Loaded 1 modules   (196616 inline 8-bit counters): 196616 [0x3f96900, 0x3fc6908), 
INFO: Loaded 1 PC tables (196616 PCs): 196616 [0x33cd138,0x36cd1b8), 
INFO:        0 files found in /tmp/libFuzzerTemp.FuzzWithFork42425.dir/C6782
INFO: -max_len is not provided; libFuzzer will not generate inputs larger than 514888 bytes
INFO: seed corpus: files: 59 min: 30838b max: 514888b total: 10611661b rss: 53Mb
#8  pulse  cov: 38701 ft: 64071 corp: 5/471Kb exec/s: 0 rss: 260Mb
#16 pulse  cov: 43230 ft: 102964 corp: 12/1418Kb exec/s: 0 rss: 519Mb
Slowest unit: 11 s:
artifact_prefix='./'; Test unit written to ./slow-unit-befe4808dffe50d5a0458238314af61206e5bd28
#32 pulse  cov: 44227 ft: 121374 corp: 28/3756Kb exec/s: 0 rss: 559Mb
Slowest unit: 15 s:
artifact_prefix='./'; Test unit written to ./slow-unit-01babca845e1d73257d1f0bb436b072147eddab1
#64 pulse  cov: 45082 ft: 155650 corp: 58/9860Kb exec/s: 0 rss: 598Mb
#64 INITED cov: 45082 ft: 155650 corp: 59/10362Kb exec/s: 0 rss: 598Mb
    NEW_PC: [REMOVED]
#65 NEW    cov: 45083 ft: 155793 corp: 60/10464Kb lim: 514888 exec/s: 0 rss: 598Mb L: 103906/514888 MS: 1 CrossOver-
#66 NEW    cov: 45083 ft: 156037 corp: 61/10610Kb lim: 514888 exec/s: 0 rss: 598Mb L: 149586/514888 MS: 1 ChangeASCIIInt-
#67 NEW    cov: 45083 ft: 156064 corp: 62/10964Kb lim: 514888 exec/s: 0 rss: 598Mb L: 362655/514888 MS: 1 ChangeBinInt-
#68 NEW    cov: 45083 ft: 156078 corp: 63/11110Kb lim: 514888 exec/s: 0 rss: 598Mb L: 149587/514888 MS: 1 InsertByte-
#69 NEW    cov: 45083 ft: 156128 corp: 64/11278Kb lim: 514888 exec/s: 0 rss: 598Mb L: 171552/514888 MS: 1 ShuffleBytes-
#70 NEW    cov: 45083 ft: 156174 corp: 65/11531Kb lim: 514888 exec/s: 0 rss: 598Mb L: 259501/514888 MS: 1 CopyPart-
#72 NEW    cov: 45083 ft: 156409 corp: 66/11699Kb lim: 514888 exec/s: 0 rss: 598Mb L: 171552/514888 MS: 2 ChangeBinInt-CopyPart-
#73 NEW    cov: 45083 ft: 156549 corp: 67/11910Kb lim: 514888 exec/s: 0 rss: 598Mb L: 216339/514888 MS: 1 InsertRepeatedBytes-
#74 NEW    cov: 45083 ft: 156554 corp: 68/12021Kb lim: 514888 exec/s: 0 rss: 598Mb L: 113500/514888 MS: 1 EraseBytes-
#76 NEW    cov: 45083 ft: 156559 corp: 69/12274Kb lim: 514888 exec/s: 0 rss: 598Mb L: 259535/514888 MS: 2 InsertRepeatedBytes-ShuffleBytes-
    NEW_PC: [REMOVED]
    NEW_PC: [REMOVED]
    NEW_PC: [REMOVED]
    NEW_PC: [REMOVED]
#79 NEW    cov: 45087 ft: 157020 corp: 70/12777Kb lim: 514888 exec/s: 0 rss: 598Mb L: 514888/514888 MS: 3 ChangeByte-ChangeByte-CrossOver-
#81 NEW    cov: 45087 ft: 157024 corp: 71/12923Kb lim: 514888 exec/s: 0 rss: 598Mb L: 149587/514888 MS: 2 CopyPart-InsertByte-
    NEW_PC: [REMOVED]
    NEW_PC: [REMOVED]
    NEW_PC: [REMOVED]
    NEW_PC: [REMOVED]
#92 NEW    cov: 45091 ft: 157249 corp: 72/13006Kb lim: 514888 exec/s: 0 rss: 598Mb L: 84803/514888 MS: 1 EraseBytes-
#93 NEW    cov: 45091 ft: 157356 corp: 73/13332Kb lim: 514888 exec/s: 0 rss: 598Mb L: 334030/514888 MS: 1 CopyPart-
#99 NEW    cov: 45091 ft: 157365 corp: 74/13543Kb lim: 514888 exec/s: 0 rss: 598Mb L: 216315/514888 MS: 1 InsertByte-
#100    NEW    cov: 45091 ft: 157377 corp: 75/13690Kb lim: 514888 exec/s: 0 rss: 598Mb L: 149586/514888 MS: 1 ChangeBinInt-
#101    NEW    cov: 45091 ft: 157384 corp: 76/14044Kb lim: 514888 exec/s: 0 rss: 598Mb L: 362655/514888 MS: 1 ChangeBit-
#103    NEW    cov: 45091 ft: 157443 corp: 77/14211Kb lim: 514888 exec/s: 0 rss: 598Mb L: 171517/514888 MS: 2 ChangeByte-InsertRepeatedBytes-
#106    NEW    cov: 45091 ft: 157446 corp: 78/14537Kb lim: 514888 exec/s: 0 rss: 598Mb L: 334084/514888 MS: 3 ChangeBit-ChangeBinInt-InsertRepeatedBytes-
    NEW_PC: [REMOVED]
#107    NEW    cov: 45092 ft: 157996 corp: 79/14705Kb lim: 514888 exec/s: 0 rss: 598Mb L: 171476/514888 MS: 1 ChangeByte-
#108    NEW    cov: 45092 ft: 157999 corp: 80/14872Kb lim: 514888 exec/s: 0 rss: 598Mb L: 171476/514888 MS: 1 CMP- DE: "Metad"-
#116    NEW    cov: 45092 ft: 158007 corp: 81/15079Kb lim: 514888 exec/s: 0 rss: 598Mb L: 211785/514888 MS: 3 ShuffleBytes-ChangeBit-CrossOver-
#117    NEW    cov: 45092 ft: 158019 corp: 82/15416Kb lim: 514888 exec/s: 0 rss: 598Mb L: 344825/514888 MS: 1 EraseBytes-
#123    NEW    cov: 45092 ft: 158036 corp: 83/15909Kb lim: 514888 exec/s: 0 rss: 598Mb L: 504648/514888 MS: 1 CopyPart-
#128    pulse  cov: 45092 ft: 158055 corp: 83/15909Kb lim: 514888 exec/s: 0 rss: 598Mb
#128    NEW    cov: 45092 ft: 158055 corp: 84/16162Kb lim: 514888 exec/s: 0 rss: 598Mb L: 259620/514888 MS: 5 CMP-InsertRepeatedBytes-ChangeBit-ChangeBinInt-CopyPart- DE: "\x91._\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00"-
#130    NEW    cov: 45092 ft: 158073 corp: 85/16Mb lim: 514888 exec/s: 0 rss: 598Mb L: 259620/514888 MS: 2 ChangeBinInt-CopyPart-
#137    NEW    cov: 45092 ft: 158137 corp: 86/16Mb lim: 514888 exec/s: 0 rss: 598Mb L: 171484/514888 MS: 2 ChangeByte-PersAutoDict- DE: "\x91._\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00"-
#138    NEW    cov: 45092 ft: 158138 corp: 87/16Mb lim: 514888 exec/s: 0 rss: 598Mb L: 338523/514888 MS: 1 CopyPart-
#144    NEW    cov: 45092 ft: 158142 corp: 88/16Mb lim: 514888 exec/s: 0 rss: 598Mb L: 171476/514888 MS: 1 ChangeASCIIInt-
#147    NEW    cov: 45092 ft: 158167 corp: 89/16Mb lim: 514888 exec/s: 0 rss: 598Mb L: 103906/514888 MS: 3 ChangeASCIIInt-ChangeBinInt-CopyPart-
#148    NEW    cov: 45092 ft: 158386 corp: 90/16Mb lim: 514888 exec/s: 0 rss: 604Mb L: 149586/514888 MS: 1 CopyPart-
#150    NEW    cov: 45092 ft: 158388 corp: 91/17Mb lim: 514888 exec/s: 0 rss: 604Mb L: 119131/514888 MS: 2 ShuffleBytes-EraseBytes-
#152    NEW    cov: 45092 ft: 158404 corp: 92/17Mb lim: 514888 exec/s: 0 rss: 604Mb L: 167390/514888 MS: 2 ChangeBit-EraseBytes-
#153    NEW    cov: 45092 ft: 158427 corp: 93/17Mb lim: 514888 exec/s: 0 rss: 605Mb L: 149586/514888 MS: 1 ChangeBit-
#154    NEW    cov: 45092 ft: 158428 corp: 94/17Mb lim: 514888 exec/s: 0 rss: 605Mb L: 149586/514888 MS: 1 ChangeBinInt-
#160    NEW    cov: 45092 ft: 158488 corp: 95/17Mb lim: 514888 exec/s: 0 rss: 605Mb L: 107319/514888 MS: 1 CrossOver-
#162    NEW    cov: 45092 ft: 158490 corp: 96/17Mb lim: 514888 exec/s: 0 rss: 605Mb L: 171553/514888 MS: 2 ChangeByte-InsertByte-
    NEW_PC: [REMOVED]
    NEW_PC: [REMOVED]
    NEW_PC: [REMOVED]
    NEW_PC: [REMOVED]
    NEW_PC: [REMOVED]
    NEW_PC: [REMOVED]
#164    NEW    cov: 45098 ft: 158729 corp: 97/17Mb lim: 514888 exec/s: 0 rss: 605Mb L: 84806/514888 MS: 2 CMP-CMP- DE: "Si"-"CCF"-
#165    NEW    cov: 45098 ft: 158800 corp: 98/18Mb lim: 514888 exec/s: 0 rss: 605Mb L: 514888/514888 MS: 1 CrossOver-
#166    NEW    cov: 45098 ft: 158815 corp: 99/18Mb lim: 514888 exec/s: 0 rss: 605Mb L: 108441/514888 MS: 1 EraseBytes-
#167    NEW    cov: 45098 ft: 158833 corp: 100/18Mb lim: 514888 exec/s: 0 rss: 605Mb L: 443842/514888 MS: 1 InsertRepeatedBytes-
#168    NEW    cov: 45098 ft: 158835 corp: 101/18Mb lim: 514888 exec/s: 0 rss: 605Mb L: 149590/514888 MS: 1 CMP- DE: "\x00\x00\x00#"-
#169    NEW    cov: 45098 ft: 158847 corp: 102/19Mb lim: 514888 exec/s: 0 rss: 605Mb L: 116574/514888 MS: 1 ChangeBit-
#175    NEW    cov: 45098 ft: 158860 corp: 103/19Mb lim: 514888 exec/s: 0 rss: 607Mb L: 149586/514888 MS: 1 ChangeBinInt-
#177    NEW    cov: 45098 ft: 158866 corp: 104/19Mb lim: 514888 exec/s: 0 rss: 607Mb L: 171476/514888 MS: 2 ChangeBinInt-CopyPart-
#178    NEW    cov: 45098 ft: 158876 corp: 105/19Mb lim: 514888 exec/s: 0 rss: 607Mb L: 149682/514888 MS: 1 InsertRepeatedBytes-
#180    NEW    cov: 45098 ft: 158946 corp: 106/19Mb lim: 514888 exec/s: 0 rss: 607Mb L: 65397/514888 MS: 2 ChangeASCIIInt-EraseBytes-
#182    NEW    cov: 45098 ft: 159002 corp: 107/19Mb lim: 514888 exec/s: 0 rss: 607Mb L: 263946/514888 MS: 2 ChangeASCIIInt-CopyPart-
    NEW_PC: [REMOVED]
    NEW_PC: [REMOVED]
    NEW_PC: [REMOVED]
#184    NEW    cov: 45101 ft: 159017 corp: 108/20Mb lim: 514888 exec/s: 0 rss: 607Mb L: 365913/514888 MS: 2 PersAutoDict-CrossOver- DE: "CCF"-
#188    NEW    cov: 45101 ft: 159033 corp: 109/20Mb lim: 514888 exec/s: 0 rss: 607Mb L: 76954/514888 MS: 4 ChangeByte-InsertByte-InsertByte-EraseBytes-
#191    NEW    cov: 45101 ft: 159055 corp: 110/20Mb lim: 514888 exec/s: 0 rss: 610Mb L: 514888/514888 MS: 3 CMP-PersAutoDict-CrossOver- DE: "\x94,\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"-"Si"-
#192    NEW    cov: 45101 ft: 159081 corp: 111/21Mb lim: 514888 exec/s: 0 rss: 611Mb L: 514888/514888 MS: 1 CopyPart-
#194    NEW    cov: 45101 ft: 159118 corp: 112/21Mb lim: 514888 exec/s: 0 rss: 611Mb L: 118409/514888 MS: 2 InsertRepeatedBytes-EraseBytes-
#195    NEW    cov: 45101 ft: 159130 corp: 113/21Mb lim: 514888 exec/s: 0 rss: 611Mb L: 334084/514888 MS: 1 CopyPart-
#196    NEW    cov: 45101 ft: 159132 corp: 114/22Mb lim: 514888 exec/s: 0 rss: 611Mb L: 362686/514888 MS: 1 InsertRepeatedBytes-
#200    NEW    cov: 45101 ft: 159134 corp: 115/22Mb lim: 514888 exec/s: 0 rss: 611Mb L: 125415/514888 MS: 4 ChangeBit-ChangeASCIIInt-ShuffleBytes-EraseBytes-
#201    NEW    cov: 45101 ft: 159139 corp: 116/22Mb lim: 514888 exec/s: 0 rss: 611Mb L: 149586/514888 MS: 1 ShuffleBytes-
#207    NEW    cov: 45101 ft: 159140 corp: 117/22Mb lim: 514888 exec/s: 0 rss: 611Mb L: 149682/514888 MS: 1 CopyPart-
#208    NEW    cov: 45101 ft: 159183 corp: 118/22Mb lim: 514888 exec/s: 0 rss: 611Mb L: 423326/514888 MS: 1 CrossOver-
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
INFO: exiting: 139 time: 540567s
```

Any ideas?  Is the fuzzer itself crashing as it is manipulating the input?  As stated, there is no core dump file so have little to go on here.

Comment: Have you executed `ulimit -c unlimited` before running your program? Core dump file won't be created if the ulimit for core file is too small.

Comment: Yes, I have set it to unlimited and am running in the context of that user.  I have executed binaries with known and expected memory faults and these do produce the expected core dump files in the working directory.

Comment: You may edit your question, add backtrace information and any relevant information you may have to help your debugging process, based on your core dump file. Can you do that?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear.  The core dump I do have is for an arbitrary application I wrote to prove to myself that the core dump mechanism was working.  It is completely unrelated to the fuzzer for which I cannot obtain a core dump file.

Comment: Oh okay, can you run your program under the GDB and produce the same segmentation fault?

Comment: I'll see what I can do.  I have had to switch tasks for the short term but will report back when I can.  Thanks for your input so far.